# What is wrong with my question about needing help understanding Deleuzian realism?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Check out this [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/help-understanding-deleuzian-realism).  Why is this still on hold after I have modified it to bring it in line with the editors' expectations?

Answer (score 1):

Reopening does not happen automatically. When you edit a question that has been put on hold, it is placed in a review queue where experienced users can vote to reopen it or leave it closed. So only some time would have been needed. I force-reopened the question now.